# Missing text editing keyboard shortcut like windows while coding

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I am a long-time PC user using macOS. I am missing some useful commands I used when coding. I know can add keyboard shortcuts but I would like to know is there already command equivalents for Mac:

1. Home Button: Go to the beginning of the line.
2. End Button: Go to the end of the line.
3. Shift + Home: Selection of the line from the cursor point to the beginning of the line (not up to the document)
4. Shift + End: Selection of the line from the cursor point to the end of the line.
5. Shift + Delete = Cut Text
6. Control + Insert = Copy text
7. Shift + Insert = Paste text

Comment: There are several websites that show the equivalences for those moving from pc to mac...

Comment: ^ There are more than you will ever manage to remember - Mac is very very keyboard 'driveable' - https://support.apple.com/HT201236

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy, Paste, Cut, Select-All Keyboard Shortcuts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12233/copy-paste-cut-select-all-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: @fsb No, it's not. Please read through my question and you will find that it's not about only cut, copy, paste and select but also moving cursor in a line and selecting in a different way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some builtin shortcuts:

1. Home (beginning of the line)  - <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>← left arrow</kbd> or <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
2. End (end of the line) - <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>→ right arrow</kbd> or <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
3. Select to the beginnig - <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>← left arrow</kbd> or <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
4. Selet to end - <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>→ right arrow</kbd> or <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
5. Cut Text - <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
6. Copy Text - <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
7. Paste Text - <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Note: You can also Kill <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⌫ backspace</kbd> (cut) and Yank <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> (paste) text.

Here's the list on [Apple Website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)